# Memory leak when I use custom compute shaders in Metal

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, metal, metal-performance-shaders

Im trying to apply the live camera filters through metal using the default `MPSKernal` filters given by apple and custom `compute Shaders`.

Im applying the custom filters on a collection view in a grid with the combination of default and the custom kernel functions.

It looks like in the app Clips.

[image]

But what I observed is that using the custom filters there is a lot of `memory leaks` compared to the default kernel functions given by apple.

I don't know what mistakes I made though if any.

Here is my custom compute shader.

```
kernel void customFunction1(

                       texture2d<float, access::read> inTexture [[texture(0)]],

                       texture2d<float, access::write> outTexture [[texture(1)]],

                       uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]]){

const float4 colorAtPixel = inTexture.read(gid);
const float4 outputColor = float4(colorAtPixel.r, colorAtPixel.g, colorAtPixel.b, 1);

outTexture.write(outputColor, gid);

}
```

Regarding to my creating my pipeline and the dispatching through thread groups the code goes here

```
let blur = MPSImageGaussianBlur(device: device, sigma: 0)

    let threadsPerThreadgroup = MTLSizeMake(4, 4, 1)
    let threadgroupsPerGrid = MTLSizeMake(destinationTexture.width / threadsPerThreadgroup.width, destinationTexture.height / threadsPerThreadgroup.height, 1)

    let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder()
    commandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(pipelineState!)
    commandEncoder.setTexture(sourceTexture, at: 0)
    commandEncoder.setTexture(destinationTexture, at: 1)

    commandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(threadgroupsPerGrid, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerThreadgroup)

    commandEncoder.endEncoding()

    autoreleasepool {
        let inPlaceTexture = UnsafeMutablePointer<MTLTexture>.allocate(capacity: 1)
        inPlaceTexture.initialize(to: destinationTexture)
        blur.encode(commandBuffer: commandBuffer, inPlaceTexture: inPlaceTexture, fallbackCopyAllocator: nil)
    }
```

The Pipeline state with the custom Shader is created like this.

```
        let defaultLibrary = device.newDefaultLibrary()

        let kernelFunction = defaultLibrary!.makeFunction(name: name)

        do {
            pipelineState = try device.makeComputePipelineState(function: kernelFunction!)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Unable to create pipeline state")
        }
```

And in instrumentation it shows there is a leak in some `Malloc 16 bytes` and in `[Mtkview draw]` method.

The screenshot is shown below.

[image]

I want help in finding where and how the issue is occurring from.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to explicitly allocate an `UnsafeMutablePointer` to store the in-place texture parameter. Incidentally, that's the source of your leak: you allocate the pointer and then never deallocate it.

Use a local variable to pass the texture instead:

```
var inPlaceTexture = destinationTexture
blur.encode(commandBuffer: commandBuffer, inPlaceTexture: &inPlaceTexture, fallbackCopyAllocator: nil)
```

By the way, you're (eventually) going to have a bad time if you call the in-place encode method without providing a fallback allocator or checking the return value. In-place encoding will fail in certain situations, so you should provide a closure that allocates an appropriate texture in the event of failure.

Comment: That worked fine. Thank you. But can you suggest me how to implement the fallback copy allocator. I tried it but it is crashing @warrenm.